# Como extraer los datos de una consulta MYSQL en .csv

Tags: mysql, base-de-datos, csv, mysql-workbench

Buenas tardes, estoy intentando sacar los datos de una consulta a un fichero .csv y no consigo que funcione. Aquí les pongo mi código.
Gracias

```
SELECT CAST(avg(numero) as decimal(18,2)) as media FROM (
SELECT
  DATE(fecha_creacion) fecha_creacion,
  COUNT(*) as numero
FROM paqueteria.paquetes

into outfile 'C:\Users\DANIEL\Desktop\prueba.csv'
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
ENCLOSED BY '"'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n'

WHERE
  fecha_creacion BETWEEN '2017-10-01' AND '2017-10-31'
  /*and hour(fecha_creacion) <= '12'*//*mañana*/
  /*and hour(fecha_creacion) >= '12'*//*tarde*/
    and remitente = 73
GROUP BY DATE(fecha_creacion)) as medias
```

Me marca como invalidas la linea 5 y la linea 10

Comment: Hola, ¿cuál es el error?

Comment: @cesar Me sale que es un error de sintaxis

Comment: Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'into outfile 'C:\Users\DANIEL\Desktop\prueba.csv' FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' ENCLO' at line 7

Comment: Tal vez sea porque la parte de la exportación debería ir al final de todo el query y no en medio de todo el query, lo estás poniendo entre el `FROM` y el `WHERE` y no creo que se acepte esa sintaxis.